# Seeking javascript (better, react) graph library

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, react

I'm seeking a long time for a graph library which support, after I tried vis.js, echarts, recharts, etc.

The project requirement is:

- collapsible tree by click node
- events on nodes / edges
- lable / tooltip on edge and node both

Better support react and render HTML components as nodes and edges.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Now I am starting to code React Native & would like such a thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, [D3JS](https://d3js.org/) is reckoned by many to be the best JS charting library that there is - just check out the great [examples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)

Googling for `collapsible D3JS` found a few hits, so it looks like it can be done. I don't have time to look further for the exact implementation details, so please Google & investigate this yourself.

See, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496291/how-to-create-d3-js-collapsible-force-layout-with-non-tree-data

And [this demo](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

There's your answer, but you have to do the coding :-)

Comment: I already google a lot. if no other choice, so we can just use d3. tnx

Comment: If so, please accept the answer - not because I want the points, but because it will help others who read ths question in future. If you think it won't help, then don't accept; I won't mind & will continue to help you in future :-)

Comment: I just want to wait a moment. Thanks

Comment: That's perfectly fine - someone may come along with a better suggestion. If they don't, after a week or so, then if you accept this it will help others who read this in future. I am just explaining because you are new. Also, it is perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question, and to accept it, because that will also help others.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try the Syncfusion [React Diagram](https://www.syncfusion.com/react-ui-components/diagram) library.

I have created a sample with collapsible nodes with a label, tooltip, and notification using diagram events. Find the sample from the below link.

sample: https://xvk22yvl4.codesandbox.io/
Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvk22yvl4

In this sample, I have created a click event for the node, when you click a node it shows an alert message. For complete API documentation, [visit here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/diagram/diagramModel)

Other related links:

[Tooltip demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/diagram/tooltip), 
[UG for Creating labels using annotation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/diagram/labels#create-annotation)

Note: I work for Syncfusion